# How to find same edges of two paths?

Tags: graph-algorithm

A path is represented by a vector, containing node id. The edge in the path has direction.

Given two paths, for example : <1,6,11,7,2,5 ...> and <3, 4, 8, 2, 7,3, 1,6...>, here <1,6> is the same edge. Sometimes the edges are successive, some times not. It's better to put a flag between these edges. For example, 
(1,2) * (5,7,9) * (6,11,12), are same edge 1->2, 5->7,7->9, 6->11, 11->12, but there is no edges from 2 to 5 or 9 to 6. So put a '*' or other symbol as a flag.

Is there anyone has some ideas? I will be appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each node has only one incoming and one outcoming edge.
Call P1 the first path of length n and P2 the second path of length m. You can turn P2 into a hashmap `startEdge -> endEdge` (e.g `<3,4,5>` would become `[3->4, 4->5]`).

Then for each element of P1, say number `i`, you compare `P1(i+1)` to `Hashmap(key= P1(i))`. If the hashmap doesn't have the key or has it but with a different value, you don't have a common edge, otherwise you do.

(If you have multiple edges for one node, values of hashmap can be Sets of Ints, and you would check whether `P1(i+1)` is contained within `Hashmap(key=P1(i))`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example solution in [Clojure](http://clojure.org/):

```
(defn same-edges [& paths]
  (->> paths
       (map (comp set (partial partition 2 1)))
       (apply clojure.set/intersection)))
```

So, for each path (`map` over all `paths`), you `partition` the path into 2-element subpaths (using a step of 1 to get all pairs of adjacent items), then calculate the `set` of all *unique* pairs attained from that partition. Then you find the `intersection` of all those sets.

Example:

```
(same-edges [1 6 11 7 2 5] [3 4 8 2 7 3 1 6])
;=> #{(1 6)}
```

In other words, the set of shared edges between the two paths represented by the vectors `[1 6 11 7 2 5]` and `[3 4 8 2 7 3 1 6]` contains only one item: the pair `(1 6)`.